# I have to call one function and get my output

Tags: python

I am having one function:

```
def divisible(num):
    if num%9 == 0:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

By using this function I have to get the output of divisible by 9 numbers between 1 and 100. How can I get that? I am very new to python, can any one help me to solve this problem.

as of now I am trying to call like this:

```
for i in range(10):
        j = divisible(i)
        if j == 'true':
            print(i)
```

But it is not giving me the exact output. I have to get like`(9,18,36,45 etc)`

Comment: You need to return true or false in the first function?

Comment: Function divisible sould be return true or false. Your loop should run more than 10

Comment: print("true") doesn't mean return True :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return instead of print.

```
def divisible(num):
    if num%9 == 0:
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"

for i in range(100):
    j = divisible(i)
    if j == 'true':
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This answers my question

Answer (score 3):

Your `divisible()` function does not *return* anything. Writing output to your console (with `print()`) is not the same as returning a result to the caller.

Since your function doesn't return a value, Python sets the return value to `None`. `None == 'true'` is never going to be true so your loop doesn't print anything.

Instead of printing, return a boolean value; either `True` or `False`:

```
def divisible(num):
    if num%9 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

or even, since `==` produces a boolean value:

```
def divisible(num):
    return num%9 == 0
```

You could still return strings of course, `return 'true'` or `return 'false'`, but Python has special objects for this and a lot of Python code can work directly with boolean values.

Now your function returns something to the caller you can test for:

```
for i in range(10):
    j = divisible(i)
    if j:
        print(i)
```

Note that `j` is either `True` or `False`, you can use that in a `if` test directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your currently **printing** `true` and `false` as values from your function. You need to `return` them.

```
def divisible(num):
    if num % 9 == 0:
        return 'true'
    else:
        return 'false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the list of numbers through `filter`:

```
lst = list(filter(lambda x: x%9, range(0,100)))
print(set(range(100)) - set(lst)
# {0, 99, 36, 72, 9, 45, 81, 18, 54, 90, 27, 63}

final_list = list(set(range(100)) - set(lst)).sort()  # to sort it
```

Comment: A shorter, more 'Pythonic' way...`[item for item in range(100) if (item%9 == 0)]`

Comment: You know, this is not a contest to show off how you'd solve the problem. Yes, there are plenty of ways you can do this with clever Python code, but  this post is not addressing the question stated *at all*.

Comment: Well OP said "I have to get like(9,18,36,45 etc)", so my solution would give him that list

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print list(x for x in range(1,101) if not x%9)
```

Which will get you:

```
[9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 99]
```